# Cannot disable proxy to install Homebrew on OS X

Tags: macos, proxy, homebrew

I'm experiencing the exact same issue as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231204/osx-proxy-issue-with-homebrew-install), but there are no answers addressing the issue.

I'm currently on my home network and trying to install Homebrew, but it fails as the terminal cannot connect to my corporate proxy. The answers in the question describe how to specify more clearly the proxy you're using to prevent this, but I do not have a proxy at all on my own wifi network.  Is there a way to simply remove the proxy settings entirely?  I've disabled all proxies in my System Preferences, and `unset http_proxy` in the shell, but it doesn't help.

In fact, there are no environment variables containing the proxy information anywhere, so I have no idea where curl is getting the information from to begin with.  I've tried running the curl command with the `--no-proxy` flag, and even deleted the variables in my NPM config, since that's the only place I can think of that the proxy URL is currently specified.  Still no luck.

Any assistance greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.  Since curl is actually downloading Homebrew through Github, it was being routed through the proxy that was set in my global Git configuration, not in my environment variables.  If anyone else runs into this:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Did the trick.

Thanks, me!